# Is there a easy-to-use program that can make a GIF / Video in which an equation is transformed?

Tags: computer-programs, equal-sign

Is there a easy-to-use program that can make a GIF / Video in which an equation is transformed?

Like this, which was make (via `PPT > Transition > Morph`), but I would like a more automated process (I enter all the steps and everything else is automatic; if the software can deduce the middle steps, that would be great):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAQgIYFaRIA

It would have to be available on Mac (which is what I use).

I know that there is the alternative of Manim, but I just couldn't get the download working and it seems to have to do with a lot of Python. Possibly just software or something online?

Comment: Hey, I don't know the answer to your question, but I'd love to steal your movie and post it on my Playlists for College Algebra. Would that be ok with you ? Nice work. I can add a link to something crediting you if you have something.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook yes

Comment: I deleted some comments here since we cleared up the link. I hope you can get a good answer!